# C# query from sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this error on query :

```
string dbserver2 = textBox4.Text;
string dbname2 = textBox1.Text;
string dbusername2 = textBox2.Text;
string dbpassword2 = textBox3.Text;

SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + dbserver + ";Initial Catalog=" + dbname + ";User ID=" + dbusername + ";Password=" + dbpassword + "");
conn2.Open();
// SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Cliente (IdCliente,IdUtente,RagioneSociale,Titolo,Indirizzo,Stato,Provincia,Citta,Comune,Cap,Telefono,Email) VALUES(@idcliente,@username,@password, @email)", conn2);
string query2 = "INSERT INTO Cliente (Titolo,RagioneSociale) VALUES(@Titolo,@RagioneSociale)";
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query2, conn2);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titolo", titolo);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RagioneSociale", ragionesociale);
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn2.Close();
```

The error is this:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name
>   'Cliente'.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

Comment: Are you _really_ sure you have a table called `Cliente` in your default schema? Is this query inserts in SQL Server?

Comment: yes the table is called Cliente @SonerGönül

Comment: Debug and check the CONNECTION STRING - conn2 , whether its connecting to correct server and DB

Answer (score 0):

Please try running the raw query directly on your database if possible and see if it is running there.

```
INSERT INTO Cliente (Titolo,RagioneSociale) VALUES(@Titolo,@RagioneSociale);
```

Put some test values in variables. If it runs there, then it is an issue related to connection string. You might need to check the initial catalog once. Please check and let me know if it works.

Comment: Wouldn't be better as a comment? EDIT: I know you need 50 rep to comment but believe me, getting 50 reputation is _not_ that hard.

Comment: i have solve the problem the textbox of server information was different

Comment: @SonerGönül Repo = 1, cant comment

Comment: @rikideveloper : Thanks for letting us know what solved your issue. Please mark the answer if you think it solved your issue.

Comment: sorry i have another error:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Cliente' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: That is a valid error. The table 'Cliente' has primary id which is set to identity in SQL server. It means sql server will generate values for that column by itself. If you do not want it to generate values and use your own values, the go to sql server management studio, open the design of the table by right clicking it and see for identity specification and turn if off and save it. Now it should work.